# Dictionary with nil: AnyObject does not have a member named 'Key'

Tags: swift

Why is this not possible?

```
var d = [AnyObject]()
d.append(["item": nil])
```

I get the error: `AnyObject does not have a member named 'Key'`

Comment: James' answer below tells you why you get the error message.  If that's not actually what you're asking, perhaps you need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

The code
    ["item" : nil] 
suggests you are trying to add a dictionary element, but you made what looks like an array.

This code: `var d = [AnyObject]()` creates an array, and the equivalent for a dictionary would be:  'var d = String : AnyObject.

Alternative ways to do this are:

```
var d : [AnyObject] = []
```

for an empty array or

```
var d : [String : AnyObject] = [:]
```

for an empty dictionary, with string keys.

Note that you won't be able to store a value for a key as 'nil' as all values for keys which don't have values are nil.  To reset the key item to nil you can use:

```
d["item"] = nil
```

to concatenate (join) dictionaries and add items, you can't use += or .append like in arrays, but for a one liner you could use:

```
for a : (key : String, value : String) in dictA { dictB[a.key] = a.value }
```

Dictionaries are v different to arrays e.g. you can't have more than one value for the same key.  You can create arrays of key value pairs and join them really easily e.g:

```
var empty : [(String , String)] = []

var full : [(String , String)] = [("A","1"), ("B","2")]

empty += full
```

Note however you can easily end up with duplicates if you do this multiple times.

Comment: Try `d.append(["item1": "myItem", "item2": nil])`. Doesn't work as well. With your way I have to say `..., "item2": ""] ... d["item2"] = nil`. Thats one additional line of code

Comment: Dictionaries are quite different to Arrays in Swift - see the edited answer for how to join on one line of code (plus arrays of key value pairs)

Comment: You say that "This code: var d = [AnyObject]() is bad practice you should do this:" but in Apple's iBook they clearly use the OP's notation.

Answer (score 0):

`[AnyObject]` is an array of `AnyObject`, so the values must be objects (instances of classes). `["item": nil]` is a dictionary literal, used to initialize a `Dictionary` (which is a struct, not a class) or other types which are `DictionaryLiteralConvertible`. The compiler can't figure out what type you want for that literal.